# How to visualize missing Inner Panels?

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, layout, jpanel

I am trying to form the following Frame:

The main Frame uses a BorderLayout.

Into at this Frame and I added a Panel which uses BoxLayout - I'll call it P1.

For some reason the Panels I add into P1 are not seen when I run the program.

What's even more confusing is that if P1 uses a GridLayout instead of a BoxLayout, all the Panels I added into P1 are shown.

The EventPanel Class used in the code extends Panel and uses a SpringLayout.

Any ideas how to make P1 work?

Here's the relevant code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        //Setting Frame
        JFrame m_CalendarFrame = new JFrame();
        m_CalendarFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Setting inner Panel
        JPanel P1 = new JPanel();
        P1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(P1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


        EventPanel Ev = new EventPanel("8:00", "16:00", "Bday", "Go party!");
        EventPanel Ev2 = new EventPanel("8:00", "16:00", "Java", "Handing Java Project");

        //Adding Two pannels into previous inner Panel
        P1.add(Ev);
        P1.add(Ev2);

        m_CalendarFrame.getContentPane().add(P1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        m_CalendarFrame.setVisible(true);

        m_CalendarFrame.setSize(800,800);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guess the problem is in your panel that uses the SpringLayout. Start by reading the Swing tutorial on [How to Use SpringLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) for working examples and explanations.

If you still need help then post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. And start simple. Try using the SpringLayout with one comopnent, then two, then three until you feel more comforatable with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with free space management, but I haven't tested it myself. The `BoxLayout` uses the preferred size for the components it draws, and the `GridLayout` distributes the available space evenly among the objects drawn.

What happens if you specify a preferred size for your `EventPanel`? Based on your code example, you can quickly test this by forcing a preferred size of (800,400) for your `EventPanel` instances, and see if it does change something when using the `BoxLayout`.